# error when installing phpmyadmin on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: phpmyadmin, lamp, ubuntu-12.04

i got a little bit error when installing phpmyadmin on my ubuntu 12.04 after following this tutorial

http://ubuntulife.net/how-to-install-lamp-in-ubuntu-12-04/

and this is the error.

http://i1193.photobucket.com/albums/aa344/hiatus1/Workspace1_001.png

anyone can solve this error? thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your LAMP setup is working fine.

Then try to restart Apache to proceed with phpmyadmin.

I answered you on my blog as well.

Comment: i've checked my apache and everythings gone well.. but i'm still confuse because my phpmyadmin still didn't works well.. :(